# Oracle CQL - Counting the number of tuples after the completion of a window

Tags: oracle, stream, cql, complex-event-processing, oracle-streams

I am working on an Oracle Event Processing Project in Oracle Stream Analytics using `JDeveloper`.

I have a data stream of 20 tuples in the form of :

```
(attr1,attr2,attr3)

1,1,1

2,2,2

....

20,20,20
```

I want to count the number of tuples within each window ( I will add a condition later to count only tuples that do not contain null values).
The desired output is :

```
10

10
```

I tried : **Select count(*) from Stream [rows 10]**. However, I get:

```
0

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10
```

I also tried: **Select count(*) from Stream [rows 10 *slide 10*]**. However I get:

```
0

10
```

My Question is how to specify a query that will return the total number of tuples (for which a condition holds) in a window of size N only when all N tuples arrive?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your second query should be ok, but you must add an having clause to have the output only when count is 10.

```
 <query id="ExampleQuery"><![CDATA[ 
    select count(*) as total from inputChannel  [rows 10 slide 10] 
    having count(*) = 10
  ]]></query>
```

[image]

hope this can help.